# why array not following the curve path

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I  have curve and array modifier. Rotation and scale is applied to mesh and curve. The mesh is not following the curve (Square). Mesh getting mess with the geometry. As soon as curve modifier added the mesh get mess. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A30601+curve+modifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things to make it work.

- Your curve's radius is messing it up. Uncheck *Radius* in the Curve properties.
- The object and Curve *origins* need to match. Set the Object's location to X=0, Y=0
- Your *curve modifier* is using the wrong axis, set it to X axis.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. A problem with the array. When i increase the count. The shape of array is not square. The corner are getting curve shape & the shape of the mesh some have square some tilted etc. https://imgur.com/gallery/STtb12s

Comment: Hello :). Please ask this as a new question. Thanks.